# how to pass attribute of type Set using postman?

Tags: java, spring, postman

so i've been trying to implement a jwt authentication/authorization example , i am trying to register a new user using **postman** but the post procedure couldn't be completed because of attribute "role" that is declared as a "Set" , i tried putting the attribute role as null like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
    "username": "jacksonBez",
    "email": "bezkoder@gmail.com",
    "role":"",
    "password": "123bezko"
}
```

and this warning has occured :

> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot coerce empty String ("") to element of
> `java.util.HashSet<java.lang.String>` (but could if coercion was
> enabled using `CoercionConfig`); nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
> coerce empty String ("") to element of
> `java.util.HashSet<java.lang.String>` (but could if coercion was
> enabled using `CoercionConfig`) at [Source:
> (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 5,
> column: 13] (through reference chain:
> com.test.jwt.payload.request.SignUpRequest["role"])]

i want to know how to use postman with a variable declared a list or a Set

here my controller's code :

```
package com.test.jwt.controller;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.jwt.model.ERole;
import com.test.jwt.model.Role;
import com.test.jwt.model.User;
import com.test.jwt.payload.request.LoginRequest;
import com.test.jwt.payload.request.SignUpRequest;
import com.test.jwt.payload.response.JwtResponse;
import com.test.jwt.payload.response.MessageResponse;
import com.test.jwt.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.test.jwt.repository.UserRepository;
import com.test.jwt.security.jwt.JwtUtils;
import com.test.jwt.security.services.UserDetailsImpl;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        
        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();      
        List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, 
                                                 userDetails.getId(), 
                                                 userDetails.getUsername(), 
                                                 userDetails.getEmail(), 
                                                 roles));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Username is already taken!"));
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body(new MessageResponse("Error: Email is already in use!"));
        }

        // Create new user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getUsername(), 
                             signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                             encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        if (strRoles == null) {
            Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
            roles.add(userRole);
        } else {
            strRoles.forEach(role -> {
                switch (role) {
                case "admin":
                    Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(adminRole);

                    break;
                case "mod":
                    Role modRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_AGENT)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(modRole);

                    break;
                default:
                    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_USER)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Error: Role is not found."));
                    roles.add(userRole);
                }
            });
        }

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("User registered successfully!"));
    }
}
```

you can also find full project here : https://github.com/bezkoder/angular-10-spring-boot-jwt-authentication

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "username": "jacksonBez",
  "email": "bezkoder@gmail.com",
  "role": {{roles}},
  "password": "123bezko"
}
```

You are missing brackets [].
"role": "" means single value
"role": [] means array/list/set of values
For postman to resole {{role}} you need to set it as global/collection or environment value for example ["admin", "mod"]

More about postman variables here
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

Comment: i tried your solution and it works fine thank you,but know i want to five it a value , it would be so helpful if you tell me how to pass a value for role attribute

Comment: You want to pass "role" as variable in postman?

Comment: i tried this as you said : ["admin", "mod"] and it didn't work ``` "timestamp": "2022-08-30T13:23:29.602+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/auth/signup"
}

Comment: Do you have roles variable in your globals?

Comment: yes i have roles var in globals

Comment: This error has nothing to do with postman. It is thrown by your code

Comment: yes i know but i think that's because i didn't pass the right value in postman

Comment: roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ROLE_ADMIN) you are fetching it from repo, if there is nothing there exception will be thrown

Answer (score 0):

First we should have the data in the DB for the roles
[image]

Then you can use this sample data to test your transaction

```
{
    "username": "test@testemail.com",
    "email": "test@testemail.com",
    "role": [
        "user"
    ],
    "password": "testPassword"
}
```

[image]